# How to FILTER using OR conditions not AND conditions

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, operators

I need to basically filter out all the data for a list of volunteers based on whether or not they are under contact later or now.

```
=FILTER({'Master Volunteer Sheet'!A2:A, 'Master Volunteer Sheet'!B2:B, 'Master Volunteer Sheet'!C2:C, 'Master Volunteer Sheet'!G2:G,'Master Volunteer Sheet'!H2:H} 'Master Volunteer Sheet'!E2:E = "y", 'Master Volunteer Sheet'!F2:F = E6"y" )
```

Here is the link to the doc
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MsnxzCHcTHD5nEnxc-fIBYAgp4ZmscTs6fQJxLjntLQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=FILTER({'Master Volunteer Sheet'!A2:C, 'Master Volunteer Sheet'!G2:H}, 
 ('Master Volunteer Sheet'!E2:E="y") + ('Master Volunteer Sheet'!F2:F="y"))
```

[image: 0]